# XAML WebView binding to string not working in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, webview, xamarin.forms

I'm new to C# and Xamarin Forms. I'm having a webview and getting source url from an API. (For this question , I have hardcode the value). I binded source url instead of adding the value to Source in XAML. But it's not working. There are few solutions in stack and forums. I tried. But didn't work. Someone please help me to sovle this.

This is my XAML

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="MyProject.Views.NewRegistration.PrivacyWebView">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <AbsoluteLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <WebView Source="{Binding WebViewSource}" HeightRequest= "300" WidthRequest="250" Navigated="Handle_Navigated" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1" />
            <ActivityIndicator x:Name="loader" IsRunning="true" IsVisible="true" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1"/>
        </AbsoluteLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

This is how I bind the source. (Tried this in Codebehind and ViewModel too)

```
 public HtmlWebViewSource WebViewSource
{
    get
    {
        return new HtmlWebViewSource { Html = "https://www.stackoverflow.com" };
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't Source for WebView just a ordinary string?

Comment: @Woj- It's a string. But I couldn't use a static text there. I have to get a web url from API in real scenario.

Comment: Have you tried changing HtmlWebViewSource to string? Binding wont work if Type is wrong.

Answer (score 4):

You're using it wrong, when using the `HtmlWebViewSource` you need to specify actual HTML instead of the URL where you want to go to. If you want to navigate to a URL, specify it in the `Source` property.

If you want to bind it, you have to implement something like this.

In your view model create a string property:

```
public string UrlToGoTo { get; set; }
```

Then set it like you normally would, make sure to have `INotifyPropertyChanged` is implemented somehow.

Then, wire up your `WebView` like this:

```
<WebView Source="{Binding UrlToGoTo}"
    HeightRequest= "300"
    WidthRequest="250"
    Navigated="Handle_Navigated"
    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1" />
```