# extendedWebView not displayed from ViewModel

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have webView and I am Binding it through ViewModel, when i debug it i know that the value is there however i cant see it. I had it set in back of the view so I know that everything works normally, but i cant display it from ViewModel. Any suggestions?

XAML

```
  <controls:ExtendedWebView
    x:Name="nameEng"
    HeightRequest="150"
    IsVisible="True"
    Opacity="1"
    Source="{Binding EN}" />
```

ContentPage

```
public Dictionary()
        {

            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = new DictionaryViewModel();
}
```

VIEWMODEL

```
 private static HtmlWebViewSource htmlSourceExplanation = new HtmlWebViewSource();
      private ExtendedWebView _en;
     public ExtendedWebView EN
            {
                get { return _en; }
                set
                {
                    _en = value;

                    NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(_en));
                }
            }

     private void SetNameAndGrammarDetail(string text, string text2)
            {
                int size = CustomFontSize;
                var style = "<style>.text{ font-size:" + size + "px !important; }</style>";

                htmlSourceName.Html = style + "<div class=\"text\"><div>" + text + "</div><div>" + text2 + "</div></div>";
                EN.Source = htmlSourceName;

                EN.BindingContextChanged += (sender, args) =>
                {
                    htmlSourceName.BindingContext = htmlSourceName.BindingContext;
                };
            }
```

Comment: I see that you expose the ExtendedWebView as property in your view model. That's not how it's supposed to be. You're basically setting the WebView.Source (from your XAML) to a new WebView. I think you should expose the HtmlText and bind the Source property to it.

Comment: Can you please show me how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are binding a `WebView.Source` from XAML to a property `EN` which is just another WebView created in the ViewModel.

What you want to do is to bind the `WebView.Source` (defined in XAML) to either HTML code or an URL.

Gerald Versluis's answer perfectly describes how you can do that:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/53101279/704281